# Linux Script Extract Information From Excel To Create Users

Tags: linux, perl

Right now I'm stuck with this project in having to pull information from an excel file to create users. The script requires the following.

- Create accounts for the employees
- Place them into his or her own department group
- Set an initial password using his or her employee ID
- Send an email containing their new account and password
- show progress with dots on the screen

I'm getting close but am getting EOF errors on line 8 and 13 see script here

```
#!bin/bash
echo $(pwd)/employeesdata.xls
Path=$($pwd)/employeesdata.xls
read Path
if [ -e $Path ];
then
Username= [ grep $(Username) $Path | cut -f1 -d `]'
Password= [ grep $(Password) $Path | cut -f2 -d `]'
useradd -- b $Username
echo $Password | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin $Username
fi
exit


I know it doesn't have the email portion yet.
```

PS-UserScript: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
PS-UserScript: line 13: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Not yet, that's why I wasn't sure if it's best to use perl or another form. I know about parsing excel files to read and print them, this is just a little more difficult.

Comment: See this is what I found which seems to be along the lines of getting close but does not indicate about being able to form this into creating users, etc.

Comment: export excel to CSV, process the csv-text file as you want. easy effective. for getting help need know more information, and we (at least me) don't want do your work. I'm glad to help, when will see, where you stuck - exactly. For now, you're heading to closed question...

Comment: @Jm666

I'm not sure what you mean by heading to a closed question. I understand, I'm not looking for you guys to do it all. It's just the fact of not having a good understanding to be able to do such a task and when it's required in a short period of time. It's as simple as the tasks that I posted above.

Comment: I tried the Cpan perl script from above but still not reading it even with the correct edit of the .xls name. Thats where i'm saying theres no specifics on whether or not to use Perl.

Comment: You can definitely use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel to get the data you want and then process. Have you installed the Spreadsheet::ParseExcel module yet? You will need to install it first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel for this task:

First make sure `cpanm` is installed:

```
$ cpan App::cpanminus
```

Then install the module:

```
$ cpanm Spreadsheet::ParseExcel
```

Once installed, you will be able to use the parsing script that you have copied into your question. That script will fetch each cell one at a time, but you'll still need to do something with those values once read. Depending on how the spreadsheet is setup (if you provide a sample or at least the headers that would be helpful), you would want to gather the info you need as you iterate over the rows, and then perform the desired actions using the data you collected.

Also, I want to point out that the file you parse has to be in the older *.xls format. ParseExcel will not parse *.xlsx files, so first save in the older format using Excel if required.

Comment: See above edit instead of using perl..

Answer (score 1):

This simple python script iterate over each cells/rows, that will be a good start I think :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'file.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Feuil1') # ws is now an IterableWorksheet

for row in ws.iter_rows(): # it brings a new method: iter_rows()
    for cell in row:
        print cell.internal_value
```

Comment: Can't use python. Thanks for your input though.....

Comment: #!bin/bash
echo $(pwd)/employeesdata.xls
Path=$($pwd)/employeesdata.xls
read Path
if [ -e $Path ];
then
Username= [ grep $(Username) $Path | cut -f1 -d `]'
Password= [ grep $(Password) $Path | cut -f2 -d `]'
useradd -- b $Username
echo $Password | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin $Username
fi
exit