# Add user account from file script error

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux Script Extract Information From Excel To Create Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664630/linux-script-extract-information-from-excel-to-create-users)

Need to create users from excel spread sheet, getting a few errors in my script on lines 8 and 13

Line 8 Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
Line 13 Syntax error unexpected end of file

```
#!bin/bash
echo $(pwd)/employeesdata.xls
Path=$($pwd)/employeesdata.xls
read Path
if [ -e $Path ];
then
Username= [ grep $(Username) $Path | cut -f1 -d `]'
Password= [ grep $(Password) $Path | cut -f2 -d `]'
useradd -- b $Username
echo $Password | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin $Username
fi
exit
```

Excel file has this and other information

```
Name (field1) EmployeeID (field2)    Phone             Address      
Joe Blow      22500033               156-454-3322       101 main
```

Comment: Is this actually an excel spreadsheet or some for of text format (like csv). Please reduce your script to what you want. It looks like you are setting Path and then reading it in.

Comment: Thanks to **not crosspost** many times (malformed) same questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664630/linux-script-extract-information-from-excel-to-create-users
 This script have absolutely no sense at all...

Comment: All I'm trying to do is read the data, export to create user accounts using the name for the username and then employeeid as the password. Following that I'm supposed to email.

Comment: well if someone could help a brother out that would be awesome4000

Comment: What help do you expect? Your script just do not make any sense AT ALL. Grepping xls file and all those $(Username) things... Do you at least have an idea how shell works and what xls file looks like from inside?

Comment: @s0me0ne it looks like what I posted below my script. It's as simple as wanting to pull the name of the person to create user account and use their employeeid as the password.... that's it

Comment: Just for starters... `read Path` does not read from the file named by `$Path`.  It reads one line from `stdin` and assigns the first word of that line to `$Path`.

Comment: bash does not read native excel files, unless it's really a text file with Tab separated values AND just happens to be named with an .xls extension. You need to make clear in your posting that your .xls file file is really a text file (which you can create in Excel using FileSaveAs -> Text-Tabs .... ). Also use `Username=$(grep $(Username) $Path | cut -f1 -d)` to populate the var `Username` with 1 value. You can never have a construct in shell like `var = ...` Spaces not allowed around `=` signs. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to refactor a few things:

```
#!bin/bash
echo $(pwd)/employeesdata.xls
Path="$(pwd)/employeesdata.xls"
read Path
if [ -e "$Path" ]; then
    Username=$(grep "$Username" "$Path" | cut -f1 -d ' ')
    Password=$(grep "$Password" "$Path" | cut -f2 -d ' ')
    useradd -- b $Username
    echo "$Password" | /usr/bin/passwd --stdin "$Username"
fi
exit
```

A few notes:

1. Quote the value you are assigning to a variable (sometimes this is not necessary, but for starting out it helps to avoid some problems)
2. Quote the usage of a variable, unless you know what you're doing. Without quoting it explicitly, the variable can generate various parameters to commands/functions.
3. `$(cmd)` executes the command `cmd` and replaces its occurrence with the output of the command.
4. `$var` or `${var}` replaces itself with the contents of variable named `var`
5. `"quoting $a"`, supposing the variable `a` contains `string` as its contents, generates the string `quoting string`.
6. `'quoting $a'`, independent of the variable `a`, generates the string `quoting $a`.
7. As confusing as it can be for newcomers, `[` is actually an "alias" for the `test` command, which can be used to compare strings, integers, and do some basic tests like checking the permissions or the existence of a file. `]` is actually just a syntax requirement just to inform the command that its parameters have ended (when called .
8. I assumed your delimiter is a space, but I could be wrong.

Hope this helps a little =)

Comment: +1 for painstook explanation. Not sure this question deserves such treatment, but keep posting! Good luck to all.